# Using Django on Runnable. cant render a simple html

Tags: html, django, templates, runnable

I'm trying to use django and render a simple html on Runnable. I guess I'm missing something obvious but I get the error "Template does not exist" all the time.

This is the code: [runnable](http://runnable.com/U-VmKmIHF-xjobRh/simple-render-problem-for-python-and-django)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set TEMPLATE_DIRS var in Django Settings (Settings.py) like the code comment says, to let Django get all the templates successfully.

Put `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"templates")` in the variable and import os.path in python. Make a templates folder inside your app folder, and move all the .html files there.